# BibTex: Don't replace repeated author with --- (ecca.bst)

Tags: bibtex

I'm using `\bibliographystyle{ecca}` along with a .bib for citing and to generate my bibliography. The style works perfectly other than it replacing repeated authors with "---" in the bibliography list, which I do not want. I tried editing the `ecca.bst` (calling it `myecca.bst` then loading `\bibliographystyle{myecca.bst}`), but I think I have been unable to identify the command that is doing the replacing. the ecca.bst is available here if anyone is able to help: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/economic/ecca.bst. Would be super grateful for any help! Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you are probably looking for this function `FUNCTION {compare.name}` that will replace the names with `---` if they are identical to the ones in the previous entries (as defined by the functions before that one). Removing this one function should do what you want, but, as I said, I didn't test it myself.

Comment: egreg's solution below worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `%` in front of `compare.name` in the function `format.names`

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  namestring 'oldnames := % Copy the stored names to the oldnames list
  "" 'namestring :=       % and blank the current name string
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      store.name
      %compare.name % Save the current name to our storage list
      bib.name.font
```

The line number is 509.

Save the file as `ecca-mod.bst` (or whatever name you prefer).

Test:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title one},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2020,
}
@article{b,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title two},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2019,
}
@article{c,
  author={W. Riter},
  title={Title three},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2021,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{a,b,c}

\bibliographystyle{ecca-mod}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, egreg! Your solution was exactly what I was after. I had failed to spot the compare.name in the function format.names. I had commented out the whole function compare.name instead which didn't quite work.